# Is there a way to find the row information in response result finding of Google DLP?

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I am sending a multiple sentence at a time as a table and using inspect_content to find personal information for each sentences.

When I use the inspect_content function, I could receive a series of findings with various information.

However, I could not find which row the each inspect result came from.

I have to deliver both original text and the location range of each target info types.

Thank you for your precious time ^^

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcjDi.png)

Comment: Please copy paste your code, it would be easier for others, than image.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rowIndex for inspect content.

Example request

```
{"item":{"table":{"headers":[{"name":"column1"}],"rows":[{"values":[{"stringValue":"not an email"}]},{"values":[{"stringValue":"test@gmail.com"}]}]}}}
```

Example response (see the table location)

```
{
  "result": {
    "findings": [
      {
        "infoType": {
          "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
        },
        "likelihood": "LIKELY",
        "location": {
          "byteRange": {
            "end": "14"
          },
          "codepointRange": {
            "end": "14"
          },
          "contentLocations": [
            {
              "recordLocation": {
                "fieldId": {
                  "name": "column1"
                },
                "tableLocation": {
                  "rowIndex": "1"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "createTime": "2022-01-05T18:15:04.413Z",
        "findingId": "2022-01-05T18:15:04.422252Z312288285164444315"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```